# Prolog Error: Clauses are not together in the source file

Tags: prolog

I'm very new to Prolog. I learned it because my lecturer lectures us students about declarative programming, and asked us to learn Prolog. So, I write this code:

```
suami(andi, maya).
anak(rini, ayah(andi), ibu(maya)).
anak(winda, ayah(andi), ibu(maya)).

suami(hari, rini).
anak(karna, ayah(hari), ibu(rini)).

suami(gibran, winda).
anak(barni, ayah(gibran), ibu(winda)).

ibu(tuti, hari).
ayah(jaka, gibran).
```

And I got this warning on my terminal:

```
Warning: c:/users/jam/ilkom/prolog/tugaspd1.pl:7:
Warning:    Clauses of suami/2 are not together in the 
source-file
Warning:    Earlier definition at c:/users/jam/ilkom/prolog/tugaspd1.pl:3
Warning:    Current predicate: anak/3
Warning:    Use :- discontiguous suami/2. to suppress this message
Warning: c:/users/jam/ilkom/prolog/tugaspd1.pl:8:
Warning:    Clauses of anak/3 are not together in the source-file
Warning:    Earlier definition at c:/users/jam/ilkom/prolog/tugaspd1.pl:4
Warning:    Current predicate: suami/2
Warning:    Use :- discontiguous anak/3. to suppress this message
Warning: c:/users/jam/ilkom/prolog/tugaspd1.pl:10:     
Warning:    Clauses of suami/2 are not together in the 
source-file
Warning:    Earlier definition at c:/users/jam/ilkom/prolog/tugaspd1.pl:3
Warning:    Current predicate: anak/3
Warning:    Use :- discontiguous suami/2. to suppress this message
Warning: c:/users/jam/ilkom/prolog/tugaspd1.pl:11:     
Warning:    Clauses of anak/3 are not together in the source-file
Warning:    Earlier definition at c:/users/jam/ilkom/prolog/tugaspd1.pl:4
Warning:    Current predicate: suami/2
Warning:    Use :- discontiguous anak/3. to suppress this message
```

what's the meaning of the warning? Is it gonna affect my code? How do I get rid of the warning?

Note:
"suami" in English is Husband,
"anak" in English is Child (anak is genderless because it's Indonesian word),
"ayah" in English is Dad,
"ibu" in English is Mom.

Answer (score 3):

You just have to sort the clauses by predicate name and arity ("arity" is the number of arguments):

```
% everything we know about the relation anak/4

anak(rini, ayah(andi), ibu(maya)).
anak(winda, ayah(andi), ibu(maya)).
anak(karna, ayah(hari), ibu(rini)).
anak(barni, ayah(gibran), ibu(winda)).

% everything we know about the relation suami/2

suami(andi, maya).
suami(hari, rini).
suami(gibran, winda).

% everything we know about the relation ibu/2

ibu(tuti, hari).

% everything we know about the relation ayah/2

ayah(jaka, gibran).
```

Alternatively you can declare a relation as "discontiguous":

```
:- discontiguous(anak/3).
```

See: [discontiguous/1](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(discontiguous)/1)

P.S. "discontiguous" as a word seems to be rather IT-specific. Merriam-Webster does not have that word in their dictionary, but they do have [noncontiguous](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/noncontiguous)

Comment: "... but that should only be used if a relation is "completed" by information in other files ..." Some mixup with *multifile* predicates? Multifile and discontiguous predicate properties are orthogonal.